# Can this analog input over-voltage protection using a Zener diode and FMMT718 transistors work?

Tags: analog, signal, protection, zener, attenuation

I have a problem in my electronic board. When I connect the signal generator 10V with my PCB in the header which contains my overvoltage protection solution based on a Zener diode, some FMMT718 transistor and resistors, I get input signal attenuation 4.78V even here my unpowered PCB.

What is this phenomenon? How do I solve it?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What do you measure where? Refer to node names in your schematic. What is the expected versus observed behavior? Have you simulated your circuit?

Comment: @JRE I mean drok signal generator .https://www.amazon.com/Generator-DROK-Adjustable-Transmitter-Simulation/dp/B071NLGP6L

Comment: What are the design parameters of the circuit, like what is the normal opperating input voltage and what is considered an over-voltage ? What is the maximum expected design current for Q33 ? etc...

Comment: @citizen the overvoltage protection block is used to protect my circuit against overvoltage greater than 10v, it is functional when I put a continuous power supply but when I apply a signal I will have an attenuation of 10v at 3.3v or and 4.7v .
-Input Voltage: 12V
-Maximum current for transistor 2A ,https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2111241030_Jiangsu-Changjing-Electronics-Technology-Co---Ltd--FMMT718_C2910189.pdf

Comment: From what I understand so far, it is 10V and above that you wish to protect - OK. So it works with 10V+ on AIN1-Con input. What do you see on the output AIN1 - this is what we want to know ? The rest I do not quite understand, about "when I apply a signal I will have an attenuation of 10v at 3.3v or and 4.7v" ?!? This is not clear to me as you explain it ... What signal are you refering to, AC or DC and where is this signal applied ? Also what is after AIN1, some type of regulator or a load ?

Comment: @citizen
 I applied a continuous signal through with the DROK signal generator equipment having the following characteristics (Power supply: DC 1-24V, Output voltage: 0-10V and output Current 0/4-20mA). for you to understand better, see the figures above.

Comment: @citizen there is a weakening of the signal, I apply 10v to the input of the generator and I connect pin 0-10V to pin AIN1 (analog input 1) of my electronic card (not powered), I find on the display 4.78v.
why this attenuation?? I don't understand?

Comment: Sorry I don't know what a DROK signal generator is, but some signal generators have an source impedance, say 50 Ohms etc. anyway a power supply is more appropriate for this type of test as you are measuring DC only ... So you are saying the voltage drop from pin 2 to pin 3 on Q33 is 5.22V ? Do you have a load on the output of AIN1 ? What is the ouput current you measure ? is Q33 getting warm or hot ?

Comment: Have you tried experimenting with a smaller value R100, like reduce to 3K or to 1K to see any difference ?

Comment: @citizen I changed the load resistor a1K, the overvoltage protection works, but at the output the signal is always at 0.
no signal transmitted!!

Comment: @TLI_Y But how do you know the OV-protection works, because you need to apply over 10V to the input, and your DROK only goes to 10V ?!? You need to apply at least 13V to make sure you go over 10V and Q33 output should be very small or 0V ...

Comment: @citizen yes, I applied a DC voltage of 12 V DC, with another DC source. it works without problem.